# Add object property from loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add property name and value from 'for loop'. However it is not working in object case. But if I use HTML form it works fine.

```
    var interestListsObj = {}
    interestLoop:function(interestList){
                var text = "";
                for(var i=0; i<interestList.length; i++) {
                    text += "<option value='"+interestList[i].machine_name+"'>"+ interestList[i].name + "</option>";
    /*line no 6*/   interestListsObj.interestList[i].machine_name =  interestList[i].name;  
                }
                $("#listOfInterest").html(text);    

                console.log(interestListsObj)                   

    },
```

In the above code if I remove the 'line no 6' then it works fine. But not sure what is wrong with the line no 6. The loop exit automatically without desire result.

Comment: Can you show us what `interestList` looks like? Are you getting any errors right now?

Comment: Use `[]` notation for creating and accessing dynamic properties. `.` won't work here. Change `interestListsObj.interestList[i].machine_name` to `interestListsObj[interestList[i].machine_name]`

Comment: you will have to declare interestListsObj.interestList[i] = {}; before line 6 if you are creating an object.

Comment: can you explan what exactly you are trying to do in line number 6
Note: interestListsObj your obj is empty so you can not read props of empty object

Comment: @ScottMarcus What I meant was he wants to use `interestList[i].machine_name` as a key for his object. He'll have to use the `interestListsObj[interestList[i].machine_name]` for that, `.` won't work

Comment: As said the property name is fine because the 'text+=' is working fine. @abhishekkannojia Thanks your code worked :) Can you answer it so I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with your way of property assignment on the `interestListsObj`
 object.
If you want use a variable or an expression to create/access a property on your object use `[]` square bracket notation. Use `.` when your property name is simple javascript identifier.

Change your code to this:

```
interestListsObj[interestList[i].machine_name] =  interestList[i].name;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer. It works fine. I will keep in mind that for dynamic properties we need '[]' brackets.

Comment: @Santosh Glad I helped. :)